# Converting String array to int (months into numbers)

Tags: c#, arrays, for-loop, initialization

Currently I have an array of 600 months (January to December) and I wanted to create a new array of int's based off of the initial array.

currently I have     ( Ignore any Legacy. as im calling the arrays from a diffrent class)

```
       for (int i = 0; i < Legacy.Month1.Length; i++)
        {

            int[] MonthNo1 = new int[Legacy.Month1.Length];

            switch (Legacy.Month1[i])
            {
                case "January ":
                    MonthNo1[i] = 1;
                    break;
                case "February ":
                    MonthNo1[i] = 2;
                    break;
                case "March ":
                    MonthNo1[i] = 3;
                    break;
                case "April ":
                    MonthNo1[i] = 4;
                    break;
                case "May":
                    MonthNo1[i] = 5;
                    break;
                case "June ":
                    MonthNo1[i] = 6;
                    break;
                case "July ":
                    MonthNo1[i] = 7;
                    break;
                case "August ":
                    MonthNo1[i] = 8;
                    break;
                case "September ":
                    MonthNo1[i] = 9;
                    break;
                case "October":
                    MonthNo1[i] = 10;
                    break;
                case "November":
                    MonthNo1[i] = 11;
                    break;
                case "December ":
                    MonthNo1[i] = 12;
                    break;
            }

            for (int j = 0; i < MonthNo1.Length; j++)
            {

                Console.WriteLine(MonthNo1[j]);

            }
```

Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work.

It successfully outputs the first converted number,  but the other 599 are all blank. On top of that at the end of the process, I get exception

> System.IndexOutOfRangeException

Relating to the `Console.WriteLine(MonthNo1[j]);` at the bottom of the code.

can anyone see where I am going wrong with this?

Comment: Well, by my logic `int[] MonthNo1 = new int[Legacy.Month1.Length]` will create new array of 600 ints for every loop taken, and `MonthNo1` will contain only 1 record at the end of first loop (hence throwing index out of range), am I right? Try pulling `int[] MonthNo1 = new int[Legacy.Month1.Length]` outside of first loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to the first problem is to move the `MonthNo1` array initialization *out* of the loop. Move the line `int[] MonthNo1 = new int[Legacy.Month1.Length];` outside the outer `for` loop. I also recommend moving the second `for` loop outside the first `for` loop, because you need to iterate over `MonthNo1` only once, not every single time you add an element to it.

The second problem is caused due to an incorrect condition in the second `for` loop. Note that in the second `for` loop the counter variable is `j`, not `i`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use switch, let create a new list. After compare, just add into new list. Try the following:

```
var monthNo1 = new List<int>();
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Legacy.Month1[i]))
{
if (Legacy.Month1[i].Trim() == "January")
monthNo1 .Add(1);
if (Legacy.Month1[i].Trim() == "February")
monthNo1 .Add(2);
...
}

for (int j = 0; i < monthNo1.Length - 1; j++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(monthNo1[j]);    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must initialise the array before `for (int i = 0; i < Legacy.Month1.Length; i++)`

remove `int[] MonthNo1 = new int[Legacy.Month1.Length];` from the **for loop**

Add it before the **for** **loop** as you initialise the array on every loop so it overwrite every times.

result:

```
int[] MonthNo1 = new int[Legacy.Month1.Length];

for (int i = 0; i < Legacy.Month1.Length; i++)
{
      switch (Legacy.Month1[i])
      {
          case "January ":
              MonthNo1[i] = 1;
              break;
          case "February ":
              MonthNo1[i] = 2;
              break;
      }

}
```